# Converting string to float won't let me operate on it

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to convert a string into a float in order to do mathematical operations on it with another string to float. However, it keeps giving me a Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int' error. I'm not sure why it's doing this, here's my code:

```
answer = float.Parse(num1_hundreds + num1_tens + num1_ones) + float.Parse(num2_hundreds + num2_tens + num2_ones);
lbl_output.Text = answer.ToString();
```

please help

Comment: Declare `answer` as `float`. You can also use `var` keyword.

Comment: ahhh thanks. Didn't think about that.

Comment: Also, since it appears that the number you're parsing is an `int` then you could use `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly declare your variable `answer` as float

```
float answer = ...
```

Or use keyword `var` for which compiler will determine the type.

```
var answer = ...
```

if it is a local variable.

if `answer` is a member of a class then only option is

```
float answer;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try casting everything to float, eg

```
answer = float.Parse(float.Parse(num1_hundreds) + float.Parse(num1_tens) + float.Parse(num1_ones)) + float.Parse(float.Parse(num2_hundreds) + float.Parse(num2_tens) + float.Parse(num2_ones));
lbl_output.Text = answer.ToString();
```

Comment: that wont work because I am combining the string in the hundreds, with the one in the tens with the one in the ones, to do a complete equation on the number resulting from that. You solution will just add up the numbers, e.g. instead of 123 which is what I want. Your solution will give me 6.